# How do I use Resource File/Path on [ToolboxBitmap("MyResourcePictureFileName")]

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Developing a custom control and want to place a custom icon. to do so trying to use solution Resource file within [ToolboxBitmap("MyResourcePictureFileName")] property but icon is not setting up instead showing default user control icon. whereas fixed path works fine

e.g. [ToolboxBitmap( @"C:\frame.bmp")]

but I don't want to use absolute location.

**QUESTION:**  How can use custom image/icon of my control

here is My code:

***Note:*** frame.bmp is already in my resource and **Action Property=Embedded Resource** for build

```
// DONT WANT TO USE THIS --> [ToolboxBitmap( @"C:\frame.bmp")]  
[ToolboxBitmap("Resources.frame.bmp")]
[ToolboxItem(true)] 
public partial class MyCustomPanelControl : Panel
{
................
................
}
```

Please advice,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   [ToolboxBitmap("Resources.frame.bmp")]
```

The resource name is not correct, a pretty chronic problem with toolbox bitmaps btw.  First make sure you embedded the bitmap correctly, do **not** use the resource designer:

- Project > Add Existing Item > select your bitmap file
- Select the added item in the Solution Explorer window.  In the Properties window set Build Action to "Embedded Resource"
- Project > Properties > Application tab > Default namespace property matters, that's the name you use instead of "Resources"
- Double-check and run ildasm.exe.  Double-click the Manifest, you should see an entry that resembles:

---

```
.mresource public DefaultNamespace.frame.bmp
{
  // Offset: 0x000000B8 Length: 0x000004F6
}
```

Note the .mresource name, that's the one you put in the attribute.  Fix:

```
[ToolboxBitmap("DefaultNamespace.frame.bmp")]
```

Replacing "DefaultNamespace" with the actual name.

Comment: first thank you for your detailed answer , I followed the exact setups which you mentioned also found entry in manifest file (in Debug folder) but no luck icon is not changing.   here is the code.

 [ToolboxBitmap("eBiz.Clients.WinSuite.frame.bmp")]
 [ToolboxItem(false)] 
 public partial class pnlMain : Panel {......................

Comment: Still doesn't look good.  Copy-paste the .mresource section you found into your question.

Comment: the namespace is same and i copy paste as you said but really no luck.     is there any format or DPI limitation for icon?

Comment: Into your *question*, nobody can look over your shoulder.

Comment: thank you , your answer seems very perfect and I know somewhere I am wrong therefore just trying and shared feedback i m sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you saved your image as a resource and you are trying to get its path with Properties.Resources.YourImage, it won`t work because the Resources is returning an image object instead of its path, as you are expecting.

If you want that to work, edit your annotation to receive an image object or save the image to a temporary file and then use its path like in:

```
string IMG_PATH = Path.GetTempPath();
IMG_PATH += "imagemsample.png"; //adds the name of the file you want
Properties.Resources.YourImage.Save(IMG_PATH);
```

Then you can:

```
[ToolboxBitmap(IMG_PATH)]
```

Comment: Dear Dom, thanks for the answer, I apologize but where to use your IMG_PATH Lines code ? are you referring something I create a class method which return save image in temp folder first and than another method so get the image path? or should I use as follows?

I cannot use this IMG_PATH lines out of control class like this.

IMG_PATH = Path.GetTempPath();
IMG_PATH += "imagemsample.png"; //adds the name of the file you want
Properties.Resources.YourImage.Save(IMG_PATH);

[ToolboxBitmap(IMG_PATH)]

public partial class pnlMain : Panel 
{
..........................
}

Pls advice.

Comment: I tried Properties.Resources.frame.....     but Properties.Resources object don't show any properties or methods as [ToolboxBitmap(...)]  line of code is out of usercontrol class therefore it is not allowing to use and show error. "Cannot resolve etc.... " you may refer [ToolboxBitmap(...)] code in my question.   thanks ones again for your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91930/discussion-between-dom-and-haseeb-ahmed).

Comment: I did some research and I've found @Hans to be the right answer. You should work on that. But please, next time specify which technology you're working on through the tag system. You should add the winforms tag. I thought you were on WPF, I only realized that was winforms after we had the conversation in chat.

Comment: @Dom, just a suggestion: next time try to convey that you know for sure the technology OP needs in your edit suggestion comment:) I came here and made sure of this, but it wasn't obvious in the edit alone.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, next time I will pay attention to that. Thank you, Andras.

Answer (score 1):

I find out some thing that can help:
If you add a image to a path `c#` doesn't make namespace for that path, you can add empty class to that path and use `typeof(thatClass)`, for example :

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ImageLoader),@"imagename.png")]
```

[image: Project Structure]

Note1: `ImageLoader` is an empty class

Note2: Make sure your image is embedded resource